# Example of a simple ASP.NET MVC + NHibernate + Fluent with proper session handling?

Tags: nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-2, fluent-nhibernate, httpcontext

I'm new to all of these technologies. I would like to see a simple (not over the top) example of how you would set up a project with these technologies. The most important being the proper NHibernate session handling (using `HttpContext`). Or we can build off of what I already have.

I've seen several examples of one piece or another but nothing with all of these technologies mixed. I'm having a tough time tying them together.

Right now I have an [`NHibernateHelper class`](http://pastebin.com/vJUNmcKP) (<-- see the pastebin link) that someone provided me as an example. I've modified it slightly. I think I need to do some stuff in my `Global.asax.cs` file but I'm not sure exactly what. I need to somehow initialize the `NHibernateHelper` by passing its constructor an Assembly... but what kind of Assembly? This is where I get really lost. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, The Assembly parameter is the Assembly that contains all Mapping files (hbm.xml) or Mapping classes (fluent nhibernate).

I'do like to recommend you to read this [Tutorial](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2011/03/03/effective-nhibernate-session-management-for-web-apps.aspx). This is how i usually do, create a new HttpModule that opens a new session once per request and binds it to the web context. At the end of the request the session is closed. [This is another example](http://blog.oenning.eti.br/tag/nhibernate/) of the same implementation, 
although the post is written in pt-BR, the code is in english.

Comment: So if I'm using Fluent how do I know what the assembly is which contains all mapping classes? That seems to be 90% of my problem right now.

Comment: Well, I looked at your code and I suppose it's the assembly that contains the namespace 'ShoeParty.Mappings'.

Comment: Do I have to create that assembly somehow?

Comment: No, you should already have it, every Project that you create on Visual Studio generates an assembly. [Try this](http://jagregory.com/writings/fluent-nhibernate-auto-mapping-introduction/), by following this example you can even remove that Assembly parameter.

Comment: Where does `SessionHelper` come from? This isn't a complete solution which ends up causing the same headaches I already have

Comment: Thanks, I've updated it to another tutorial that should be almost the same.

Comment: Both links are dead.